# Execute a method after a delay with cancellationToken

Tags: c#, async-await, timer, task-parallel-library, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm writing a routine in a multiplayer game environment using C#.net core.

Scenario: if in case player doesn't respond with in a certain time, timeout occurs and server respond on player's behalf (player.autoPlay) and game move on to next player.
For that a Task delay is introduced with a cancellation token.

When player actually responds with-in certain time, token cancels the delay task and exception occurs and it avoids running Player.AutoPlay().

```
public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; private set; } = new CancellationTokenSource();

public async Task CreateFallbackforPlayerTurn(string msg, Player player)
{
    var fakeDto = new dto{value = "something"};
    try
        {
            await Task.Delay(DefaultTimeout, TokenSource.Token);
            var resp = player.AutoPlay(fakeDto);
            OnPlayerResponse(resp, true);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"fallback canceled as player responded, { ex.Message}");
        }
}


public async Task ActionFromClient(Dto actualResponse)
{
    OnPlayerResponseactualResponse, false);
}


public void OnPlayerResponse(Dto dto, bool fromAutoPlayer = false)
{
  if (fromAutoPlayer == false)
  {
     TokenSource.Cancel();
  }
  ProcessResponse();
}
```

The above code works fine.

My question here are,

1. Is Task are the best way to achieve the objective or using Timer.start, OnTimedEvent & Timer.stop would play a better role here.
2. Here exception is used as a normal logic, which I'm not willing to digest. Is there a way I can avoid raising exception and still avoid autoplay method execution.
3. In terms of scalability, what is the load/performance hit because of Task.dalay when a million users connected.
   One task created for each user every turn. (I believe TokenSource.Cancel destroy it as well after each turn). So active tasks at a time are number of users connected.

Happy to hear your views.

Comment: Under the hood [Task.Delay] uses a timer, as shown in [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,5863). imho there is nothing wrong using a Task for this.

Comment: @KumarShishir Have you considered to use [Polly's Fallback](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback) and [Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) policies? Your wait logic could be wrapped into a Timeout policy and in case of failure your Fallback logic can call the auto play.

Comment: @PeterBons This solves my first issue, thanks

Comment: @PeterCsala I started liking this approach. Not only fallback and Timeout it has more options like waitRetry & circuitBreaker. Do you have some samples?  I finiding difficulty in setting fallback Policy.    AsyncTimeoutPolicy timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(30, TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic);
            var fallbackPolicy = Policy.xxx(OnPlayerResponse(fakeDto, true));
            var policyWrap1 = Policy.WrapAsync(fallbackPolicy, timeoutPolicy);
            var policyWrap2 = fallbackPolicy.Wrap(timeoutPolicy);

Comment: I honestly think Polly is just an abstraction that hides the timers and handling of the 
 OperationCanceledException , so in terms of the original question, it wouldn't improve the existing code much. That said, Polly still is a great library.

Comment: That's true @PeterBons, however it provides a uniform way to implement some specific scenarios. Still I'm yet to verify the scalability part (3).

Comment: @KumarShishir `var fallbackPolicy = Policy<Dto>.Handle<TimeoutRejectedException>.FallbackAsync(...` If I will have time I'll post an answer later in this week.

Comment: Reflecting to your 3rd question: Maintaining a million active connections / service instance seems really unrealistic. If you have to deal with huge amount of connections (and state) then Actor model (for example: [Akka.net](https://getakka.net/)) should be considered as a viable alternative.

Comment: @KumarShishir I've posted as an answer a sample application where I've simulated the user interaction. Because of that the implementation is a bit more complex than what you really need. But it does contains everything about how to use Polly for this particular scenario. I hope it helps you a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put together a sample application which uses [Fallback](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback) and [Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) to achieve the desired behaviour.

I've used the following dummy classes for `Player` and `Dto`:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public Dto AutoPlay(Dto dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(AutoPlay)} method has been called.");
        return dto;
    }

    public Dto Play(Dto dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Play)} method has been called.");
        return dto;
    }
}
```

The policy definitions look like this:

```cs
const int TimeoutInSec = 10;
var player = new Player();

var timeout = Policy
    .TimeoutAsync<Dto>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeoutInSec));

var fallback = Policy<Dto>
    .Handle<TaskCanceledException>()
    .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
    .FallbackAsync(_ => Task.FromResult(FallbackFlow(player)));

var strategy = Policy.WrapAsync(fallback, timeout);
```

Just a couple of notes regarding these policies:

- In case of Timeout you can specify the return type at the `TimeoutAsync<T>` method call.
- In case of Fallback you can specify the return type at the `Policy<T>` class level.
- Even though the `FallbackFlow` is sync we need to use `FallBackAsync` to be able to connect fallback policy to the timeout policy (inside the `WrapAsync`).
- This fallback policy will handle timeout policy's failure (`TimeoutRejectedException`) and `CancellationToken`'s Canceled exception (`TaskCanceledException`).

The definition of the `FallbackFlow` is this simple:

```cs
public static Dto FallbackFlow(Player player)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(FallbackFlow)} has been called.");
    return player.AutoPlay(new Dto { Value = "fallback" });
}
```

The definition of the `NormalFlow` could be way simpler than mine. I used this because I had to create a user input simulator (after a random period of time it will respond).

```cs
public static async Task<Dto> NormalFlow(Player player, CancellationToken timeoutPolicyToken, 
    Task<Dto> channelFromSimulator, CancellationTokenSource channelToSimulator)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NormalFlow)} has been called.");
    await Task.WhenAny(channelFromSimulator, Task.Delay(1000000, timeoutPolicyToken));
    
    if (!channelFromSimulator.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NormalFlow)} has been canceled");
        channelToSimulator.Cancel();
        timeoutPolicyToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    var dto = await channelFromSimulator;
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NormalFlow)} has received user data.");
    return player.Play(dto);
}
```

A couple of notes regarding this implementation:

- The `Task.WhenAny` is used to wait either for the user input `channelFromSimulator` or for the timeout policy to trigger `Task.Delay(1000000, timeoutPolicyToken)`

  - If the timeout policy triggers then the `timeoutPolicyToken` will be cancelled
- When the timeout policy has triggered then the other job has failed so `channelFromSimulator.IsCompletedSuccessfull` will be `false`.

  - We have to notify the simulator to stop working: `channelToSimulator.Cancel();`
  - we have to notify our strategy to escalate the problem to the fallback policy: `timeoutPolicyToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`
- If the timeout has not triggered then we retrieve information from the Simulator: `var dto = await channelFromSimulator;`

The simulator implementation looks like this:

```cs
public static async Task SimulatePlayer(TaskCompletionSource<Dto> channelToNormalFlow, 
    CancellationToken channelFromNormalFlow)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    var userResponseInSec = rand.Next() % 20;
    Console.WriteLine($"Simulator will respond in {userResponseInSec} seconds");
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(userResponseInSec), channelFromNormalFlow);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Simulator has been canceled");
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Simulator is about to respond");
    channelToNormalFlow.SetResult(new Dto { Value = "user provided data" });
}
```

A couple of notes regarding the implementation:

- The `Task.Delay` will either wait for a random number of seconds or until the simulator is cancelled `channelFromNormalFlow`
- If it is cancelled then it will silently exit
- If it is not cancelled then it will produce some dummy data and sends it to the `NormalFlow`: `channelToNormalFlow.SetResult`.

---

As you can see I've used `TaskCompletionSource` to pass data from `SimulatePlayer` to `NormalFlow`:

- SimulatePlayer: `channelToNormalFlow.SetResult(new Dto {...});`
- NormalFlow: `var dto = await channelFromSimulator`

And I've used `CancellationTokenSource` to stop the `SimulatePlayer` from the `NormalFlow`:

- NormalFlow: `channelToSimulator.Cancel();`
- SimulatePlayer: `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(userResponseInSec), channelFromNormalFlow)`

---

Finally let's put all these pieces together:

```cs
var normalFlowToSimulator = new CancellationTokenSource();
var simulatorToNormalFlow = new TaskCompletionSource<Dto>();
var theJob = strategy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) => await NormalFlow(player, ct, simulatorToNormalFlow.Task, normalFlowToSimulator), normalFlowToSimulator.Token);

await Task.WhenAll(theJob, SimulatePlayer(simulatorToNormalFlow, normalFlowToSimulator.Token));
var response = await theJob;

Console.WriteLine($"Result: {response.Value}");
```

Just a couple of notes:

- As I said I've used to different objects to handle the communication between `SimulatePlayer` and `NormalFlow`:  `normalFlowToSimulator`, `simulatorToNormalFlow`
- `ct` is a combined/linked `CancellationToken`. The timeoutPolicy's token and our `normalFlowToSimulator`'s token.
- I run the `NormalFlow` (inside a resilient strategy) in parallel with the `SimulatePlayer`.
- When both of them finished I retrieve the result.

Output of a normal run when simulator responds in time:

```
NormalFlow has been called.
Simulator will respond in 4 seconds
Simulator is about to respond
NormalFlow has received user data.
Play method has been called.
Result: user provided data
```

Output of a fallback run when simulator does not respond in time:

```
NormalFlow has been called.
Simulator will respond in 14 seconds
NormalFlow has been canceled
Simulator has been canceled
FallbackFlow has been called.
AutoPlay method has been called.
Result: fallback
```

Answer (score -6):

```
  var source = new CancellationTokenSource();  
              CancellationToken token = source.Token;  
              Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {   
                for(int i=0;i< 10000;i++)  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(i);  
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)  
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();  
                }  
              }, token);  
              source.CancelAfter(1000);
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm pretty sure the task will complete before the cancellation is fired.

Comment: Don’t do this: 1) According to the documentation Task.Run is preferred over Task.Factory.StartNew. 2) Always await your tasks. 3) Your if check is unnecessary as ThrowIfCancellationRequested already does the check.